# Merge array of objects to array of arrays each containing 3 objects

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have the following JavaScript array of many many objects:

```
[
    {...},
    {...},
    {...},
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    {...},
    {...}
]
```

I would like to transform the array to rows of 3 objects, something like this:

```
[
    [ {...}, {...}, {...} ],
    [ {...}, {...}, {...} ],
    [ {...}, {...}, {...} ],
    .
    .
    .
    [ {...}, {...}, {...} ],
    [ {...}, {...}, {...} ]
]
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Do you know the ways to do that and want to know which is the best or do you not know any way to do that?

Comment: What criteria will you use to decide which array each object should go into?

Comment: @Renato Lochetti: I always can do it with for statements and loops. I am looking for the efficiect and lesdd code as possible. Maybe there is any hidden function of an array that do such thing that I don't know.

Comment: @jalynn2: I don't have criteria, each 3 objects should be in one row. I need to transform array to grid.

Comment: In terms of asymptotic time you always need to iterate for the entire vector. Just a loop and get three at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yet another snippet (adapted from @Florent)

```
var result = [];

do {
   result.push( data.splice( 0, 3 ) )
} while( data.length );
```

Comment: What if data.length % 3 <> 0 ?

Comment: @Naor: well, this code will greedily grab 3 items from the target array and write those into `results`. If there are less than 3, it'll take whatever is left.

Comment: it was flawed anways, fixed that with `.push` instead of `.concat`

Answer (score 2):

Use a `for` loop:

```
var i = 0
  , n = data.length
  , result = [];

for (; i < n; i += 3) {
  result.push([data[i], data[i + 1], data[i + 2]]);
}
```

Comment: preceeding... commas.. argll.. it.. hurts... my.. eyes.. argggh..    +1 anyway :p

Comment: fixed it. By the way, the code can get improved by invoking `Array.prototype.splice` instead using offsets `i+n`.

Comment: The last row might contains undefined where data length is not devided bt 3.

Comment: According to the OP's question I supposed that `data.length % 3 == 0`

Comment: The suggested resulting array suggests that :P

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a loop. This takes the array `items` and creates the array `result`:

```
var result = [];
var line;
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  if (i % 3 == 0) {
    line = [];
    result.push(line);
  }
  line.push(items[i]);
}
```

(This way of looping works even if the source array is not exactly divisible by three.)

Comment: You never push the last row if it doesn't divided by 3.

Comment: @Naor: Yes, it does. The row is pushed to the array right after it is created, not after it has been filled with items.

Answer (score 0):

Just another option :)

```
var result = arr.reduce(
    function(prev, curr, index) { 
        if(index > 1) { 
            if(prev[prev.length-1].length == 3) 
                prev.push([]); 
            prev[prev.length-1].push(curr); 
            return prev; 
        }
        return [[prev, curr]]; 
    }
);
```